# Using a PList to integrate with buttons, not a table view

Tags: ios, objective-c

Right now I have a quiz that I made that has five seperate categories. There are certain stipulations that I need to keep in order for it to be used in its intended use. I started out with a simple switch statement to run the program because it made sense to me at the time and I thought I would be able to manipulate the quiz to run the way I want. Well, long story short I ran into one issue. My quiz runs like this:

Intro screen> Category selection screen where the user chooses one of the five categories > Question screen. But, the way that it runs after a user answers a question, it displays the correct answer and whether they were correct or incorrect and displays a button to go back to the selection screen. I could not figure out how to run through an entire category of questions and still maintain that correct/incorrect screen that displays each answer between each and every question. This is a learning tool, not a strict test and if they can't see the correct answer it is pointless.

So I started reading up on PLists. Trying to make this a more dynamic code has been confusing, but the only way I have figured out how to use PLists is using a table view, which changes up my GUI. Is there a way to still integrate a PList but maintain my same buttons and UILabel that will change with each question?

I.E here is an example how how it is now:

UILabel (This label hides until after a question is selected where it changes to Correct/Incorrect)
UILabel (changes with each different question)

Button1 (These four buttons changes with each respective answer)

UILabel (This label stays hidden until after a question is answered then will appear with the correct one)

Button2

Button3

Button4

All four buttons are set to hide after one is selected.

Is there a way pull data from the plist instead of using a table view to make the quiz. The spacing and the background image depends on using this type of interface over the tableview.

A side note question would be, would using Core Data be able to use this approach? Not a super important question because I think that Core Data from what it looks like is much too advanced for me. I do have a 2500 question quiz I will be making though pretty shortly and was thinking about looking it this.

Thanks for the help again guys! You have been very helpful. Is there way to get in contact with developers for more private help? I am currently deployed right now and it has made it very difficult finding any help while I am learning. So far I have read through Programming Objective C 6th edition and am about to start on the iOS development book I have and it would be nice to have someone to shoot a simple question to for a little clarity.

Comment: For 1:1 questions you could consider something like http://www.airpair.com

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to create a singleton question controller (or at least instantiated a single instance with the selected category). Your other view controllers should probably be recreated each time you move to a new question / answer. The question controller manages knowledge of the selected category and which questions have been answered. It can also manage the score, question randomisation, etc.

The plist makes little difference really, only the question controller should know of it's existence (also the category controller perhaps).

2500 questions depends on the amount of text. Try it and see. The problem with a plist is that it is all loaded in memory at the same time. You could use a plist for the structure and other files for the text content of each question / answer.

Comment: Okay that makes sense that the plist would load all the memory at once. I am not familiar with singleton. I am googling it right now in an attempt to understand more.